# Browser plugin for measuring PDF

Tags: pdf, browser, plugins, measure

Is there a browser plugin that can allow a user to measure objects on a PDF in the browser window? It needs to be cross-browser.

Comment: This is a cross post from webmasters...  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/browser-plugin-for-measuring-pdf

Comment: And Superuser (http://superuser.com/questions/223520/browser-plugin-for-measuring-pdf) and Web Apps (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10463/browser-plugin-for-measuring-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

This functionality has to be built into the PDF reader plugin.  There is a limited API to the Adobe PDF reader, but I don't believe it has the functionality you speak of.  Besides, not everyone uses Adobe's reader.

Perhaps if you give us a higher level view of what you are trying to accomplish, we could suggest alternatives.

Comment: The construction company I work for has a file server and most of the drawings are in PDF format (many of the other people we deal with don't use a CAD program, they just want PDF).  I want them to be able to take measurements on the PDF in the browser.  I know there are programs that can be downloaded for this, but just to keep is simple, I'd like to try to have that feature in a browser plugin.  *edit* Also, we are not the ones who create these drawings, we just receive them from the consultants in PDF or TIFF format, so saving them to another format direct from CAD is not an option.

Comment: How can you take measurements without knowing the scale?  I don't think your source files are going to have enough information.  Mind posting a link of a downloaded program that does what you want?

Comment: The scale is displayed on the drawing.  FoxitReader has this function.  It's just a popup box, you put in the scale that is shown on the drawing, then start measuring